# $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{1-\left(\cos x\right)^{\ln\left(x+1\right)}}{x^{4}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Could you please check if I derive the limit correctly?

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{1-\left(\cos x\right)^{\ln\left(x+1\right)}}{x^{4}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{1-\left(O\left(1\right)\right)^{\left(O\left(1\right)\right)}}{x^{4}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{0}{x^{4}}=0$$

Comment: Incorrect. Where is the justification for any of this? You can't just operate with big-O notation.

Comment: Why? As x goes to 0, cos x and log (1 + x) are bounded by O(1), which follows from Taylor expansion.

Comment: See my answer (just posted) to see what other false statements you can prove using your logic.

Comment: I agree, of course, that $\cos x$ and $\log(1+x)$ are bounded by $O(1)$, but $O(1)\neq 1$, you can't just say $1-O(1)=0$. And even if you could, you only proved that the numerator has a value of $0$ as $x=0$, and since the denominator also has that, the expression is $\frac00$ which is *NOT* zero.

Comment: As an aside, $~\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}~\frac{1-(\cos x)^{\ln(x+1)}}{x^\color{red}3} ~=~ \frac12.~$

Comment: @Lucian, so my limit doesn't exist.

Comment: @Mirak: Yes, precisely. The limit diverges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$1-(\cos{x})^{\log{(1+x)}} = 1-e^{\log{\cos{x}} \log{(1+x)}} $$

$$\begin{align}\log{\cos{x}} &= \log{\left ( 1-\frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!}+\cdots \right )}\\ &= \left (-\frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!}+\cdots \right ) - \frac12\left (-\frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!}+\cdots \right )^2+\cdots \\ &= -\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{12} + \cdots \end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}\log{\cos{x}} \log{(1+x)} &= \left ( -\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{12} + \cdots \right ) \left (x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{x^4}{4}+\cdots \right )\\ &= -\frac{x^3}{2} \left ( 1+\frac{x^2}{6}+\cdots \right ) \left (1 - \frac{x}{2} + \frac{x^2}{3} +\cdots \right ) \\ &= -\frac{x^3}{2} + \frac{x^4}{4} + \cdots \end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}1-e^{\log{\cos{x}} \log{(1+x)}} &= -\left (-\frac{x^3}{2} + \frac{x^4}{4} + \cdots \right ) - \frac1{2!} \left (-\frac{x^3}{2} + \frac{x^4}{4} + \cdots \right )^2+\cdots \\ &= \frac{x^3}{2} - \frac{x^4}{4} + \cdots\end{align}$$

Thus,

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-(\cos{x})^{\log{(1+x)}}}{x^4} = \lim_{x\to 0} \left (\frac{1}{2 x} - \frac14 + \cdots \right) = \infty $$

Answer (score 0):

By your logic:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1 - \cos x}{x^2} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-O(1)}{x^2} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{0}{x^2} = 0$$

but in actual fact, the limit should be equal to $\frac12$

Comment: This is an easy one. I can check by L'Hopital's rule. BTW, did my mistake arise from the fact that I use not enough terms? For example in your example, the expansion $1 - \frac{x^2}{2}$ gives correct limit.

Comment: @Mirak Your mistake was double: yes, you used too little terms, but you also failed to notice that. The thing is you got a limit of $\frac00$, and you should not have said "that's 0", you should say "oh, I guess I should have taken more terms"

Comment: @Mirak Also, you can do L'Hospital's rule on your example too. You just need to do it several times.

Comment: I started to do L'Hopital but it brought me even bigger expression, so I switched to Taylor expansion. But using Taylor expansion with terms up to $x^4$ looks even more difficult to compute. Is there any other (less computationally demanding) way to solve it?

Comment: @Mirak Not that I know of. Also, taylor's expansion may not be the best idea because the expansion of $f(x)^{g(x)}$ is very very complicated.

Comment: @5xum: I agree that Taylor expansions can be difficult to compute sometimes. Hence I have provided an answer without Taylor (and without L'hospital too).

Comment: @5xum: What do you mean by "very very complicated"? It's trivial and Ron Gordon did exactly that.. You never compute the Taylor expansion of $x \mapsto f(x)^{g(x)}$ itself, but rather you just compute the expansions of $f$ and $g$ separately and then substitute them (including the error-terms) into $x \mapsto \exp(g(x)\ln(f(x)))$.

Answer (score 0):

We can proceed as follows:
\begin{align}
L &= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1 - (\cos x)^{\log(1 + x)}}{x^{4}}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1 - \exp\{\log(1 + x)\log(\cos x)\}}{x^{4}}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1 - \exp\{\log(1 + x)\log(\cos x)\}}{\log(1 + x)\log(\cos x)}\cdot\frac{\log(1 + x)\log(\cos x)}{x^{4}}\notag\\
&= \lim_{y \to 0}\frac{1 - e^{y}}{y}\cdot\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\log(1 + x)}{x}\cdot\frac{\log \cos x}{x^{3}}\notag\\
&= -1\cdot 1\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\log(1 + \cos x - 1)}{x^{3}}\notag\\
&= -\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\log(1 + \cos x - 1)}{\cos x - 1}\cdot\frac{\cos x - 1}{x^{3}}\notag\\
&= -\lim_{z \to 0}\frac{\log(1 + z)}{z}\cdot\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\cos^{2}x - 1}{x^{3}(\cos x + 1)}\notag\\
&= -\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{1 + \cos x}\cdot\frac{-\sin^{2}x}{x^{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{x}\notag\\
&= -\frac{1}{2}\cdot (-1)\cdot\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{x}\notag\\
&= \infty
\end{align}

Here $y = \log(1 + x)\log(\cos x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$ and $z = \cos x - 1 \to 0$ as $x \to 0$. We see that effective use of standard limits is sufficient in many seemingly tough limit problems and there is no need for higher level theorems like Taylor or L'Hospital Rule.

Also as mentioned in one of the comments (to the question) we can see that had the denominator been $x^{3}$ there would not have been the factor $1/x$ in the second last line of our derivation and the limit would have been $1/2$.

Comment: Coolest answer hands down